# With VS Code and Python, Intellisense doesn't suggest me the pywhatkit import definitions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

Problem: Start VS Code and when calling a function from a package, for example pywhatkit,
autocompletion or Intellisense doesn't suggest package functions to me.

P.S:
Language: Python.
I am using a virtual environment.
I have downloaded pywhatkit and its dependencies.

Intellisense only works again if:

1. I delete the imports of the file
2. Close VS Code
3. I write again the import

But of course, when I close VS Code and open it again, the problem persists again.
Has anyone else had this happen or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether you have chosen the correct python interpreter by shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type **Python: Select Interpreter**.
2. Ensure that your virtual environment has been activated.
3. You could try to reinstall the python package by command `pip install packageName`.
4. If it still doesn't work, try to **reinstall [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)** or switch to pre-release version.